# LINQ to Objects Dynamic query operators

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on LINQ to Objects Dynamic Query syntax. The examples I've seen so far all do the obvious stuff like

```
query = query.Where(String.Format("{0} >= \"{1}\"", FieldName, Value));
```

This is a bit ambiguous because I can't tell whether we're using SQL operators or Linq Operators (.Contains(), StartsWith(), etc).

Does anyone know where I can find detailed info on this? Not even Scott Guthrie's blog has the info I'm after.

What I'm doing is building a web-based dynamic query interface for items stored in a CSV. The user will be able to select conditions like

`WHERE [FIELDNAME] [OPERATOR] [VALUE]`, e.g. WHERE **country** **endswith** '**stan**'

My code so far is thus

```
foreach (var op in operators)
{
    switch (op.Operator)
    { 
    case "startswith":
        source = source.Where(String.Format("{0}.StartsWith(\"{1}\")",  op.FieldName,op.Key));
        break;
    case "endswith":
        source = source.Where(String.Format("{0}.EndsWith(\"{1}\")", op.FieldName, op.Key));
        break;
    case "contains":
        source = source.Where(String.Format("{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", op.FieldName, op.Key));
        break;
    //case "regex":
    //        source = source.Where(String.Format("{0} like '{1}%'"), op.FieldName, op.Key);
    //        break;
    case "exactly":
        source = source.Where(String.Format("{0} == \"{1}\"", op.FieldName, op.Key));
        break;
    case "doesnotcontain":
        source = source.Where(String.Format("!{0}.Contains(\"{1}\")", op.FieldName, op.Key));
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Best thing here would be to just use oData queries.

Comment: What do you mean by oData queries? I'm only familiar with the REST Open Data Protocol, which I guess is NOT what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about it, you don't need to use REST for it, there are nuget packages like Linq2QueryString that will build dynamic queries for you.

Comment: How would I implement a collection of operators using OData? I would for instance have a number of conditions for the email or phone or country fields.

Comment: There's some stuff on expression trees on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx that might help in how to build a query; I don't know how you would issue it against a CSV file though.

Comment: The CSV is turned into an IQueryable.

Comment: I think expression trees are probably to way to go. I can see from the DynamicQuery source that it doesn't implement Contains() at all, so I'd have to extend it, which I don't want to do because when Nuget decides to update it in future, I'd have to do it again.

Comment: You can always also try https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: The provided link simply states that the documentation is not sufficient.